# Every 15 minutes some reason session expire and redirect to login page

Tags: php

I have this in my code but it does not seem to have any affect on the server. I set `session gc_maxlifetime` time 4 hours but it does not work. Every 15 minutes it redirects to the login page.

What can I change to avoid unexpected session expiration? In Local it works fine but on the server it create problem.

```
    ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
    ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);
    ini_set('session.cookie_secure', FALSE);
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', TRUE);
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',14400);   //4 hour          
    setcookie("_lid", $lid, time() + 14400);

    //set cokkies expiretime
    $sessionCookieExpireTime=8*60*60;
    session_set_cookie_params($sessionCookieExpireTime);
```

Comment: Set the `save_path` to a path only _your application_ stores its cookie data. If you are using a shared folder, the shortest timeout 'wins' (cleans up you sessions with its garbage collector).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the session garbage collection is done via a cronjob under `/etc/cron.d/php` or `/etc/crontab`.

This is set to every 30 minutes afaik.

Change it to `0 */4 * * *` to let it do its job every 4 hours.

The cronjob looks like:

```
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -delete
```

To advertise my personal opinion, I'd install `memcached` server and use it as your session handler. It's faster and better to control without a cronjob deleting your files.